# Extract link from IMDB table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch links from IMDB webpage. Inside table there are links but i get this error I don't know how to fetch links i am beginner plz help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

var_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top")

var_html  = var_file.read()

var_file.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(var_html)
for item in soup.find_all(tbody={'class': 'lister-list'}):
    for link in item.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

I get this error

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was ex
plicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system
("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another syst
em, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and beh
ave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

Comment: Just a side note: Keep in mind that IMDb doesn't allow scraping. So if you're scraping too much data,  they might ban your IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
soup.find_all(class_='lister-list')
```

Comment: thanks for help but it says F:\>python links1.py
  File "links1.py", line 10
    for item in soup.find_all(class_='lister-list')
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  i suppose syntax is class='.lister-list' but same error

Comment: hey thanks a lot it worked everything was perfect i missed : after soup.find_all(class_='lister-list') since it was in for loop

Comment: here is the working code ` from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

var_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top")

var_html  = var_file.read()

var_file.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(var_html, "lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_='lister-list'):
 for link in item.find_all('a'):
  print(link.get('href'))`

Comment: Good.  By the way: `class` is reserved keyword for Object Programming so BS use `_` in `class_`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning, says you didn't select the parser...

Instead of

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(var_html)
```

Try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(var_html, "lxml")
```